# Add object represented only by interface to a ORM generated collection of entities

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to use IoC on small project for which I use one commercional ORM.

There is collection of 'User' Entites on my Entity 'Project'. When I pass an interface to the method, I'm unable to add th eobject to the collection of 'User' entities, because it is represented by some ORM EntityCollection class.

Example:

```
//'this' is a partial class to the modeled Entity<int>
public void AddToCollection(IUser user)
{
    this.Users.Add(user); //this.Users is type of EntityCollection.
}
```

I see the two possibilities here and I don't know which one is the best practice.

1. Change the EntityCollection to IEnumerable (which is not possible)
2. Cast IUser to User

Or may be I'm going completely wrong way wiht IoC, what is the best practice here?

Comment: By IoC do you mean you're using dependency injection and a container? If you are loading and saving `User` instances through your ORM, then it's not clear why you have an `IUser` interface at all, and how this relates to using a DI container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for me, it's not a good to use interface for entities. prefer base class instead.
Best regard

Comment: Using interfaces for entities pays off when building a repository layer. You can then have multiple implementations of repositories for different ORMs. On the other hand, it is really difficult to have the same base classes for entities generated for EF, Linq2SQL and NH (especially when entities are autogenerated).

Answer (score 0):

Cast. For example:

```
//'this' is a partial class to the modeled Entity<int> 
public void AddToCollection(IUser user) 
{   
     if ( user is User )  
         this.Users.Add( (User)user ); 
     else
         throw new ArgumentException();
}
```